# Formula for comparing Date Fields

Tags: formula

I have a report which has a filter contact: created date not equal to website inquiry: created date, however it is not working. I created a formula on the website object Contact__r.CreatedDate  <>  CreatedDate however it is not working. Could someone please assist me in figuring this out because For some reason, SFDC does not support comparisons between two fields.

Comment: CreatedDate stores more than just the Date. It goes all the way down to milliseconds. Is your filter returning all records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the CreatedDate fields are never matching because they store the time part as well. If you just want to compare the date parts, try this in your formula:

`DATEVALUE(Contact__r.CreatedDate) <> DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)`

Comment: Hey Daniel, yeah my filter was returning all records. I will try this out and let you know how it works. Thanks very much